# absolutely convergent series in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces, absolute-convergence

Is it possible to find an infinite dimensional Hilbert space, where every convergent series is absolutely convergent?

I could not find any clue to find an example of such type or to disprove that. Please give a hint.

Comment: @Pedro: But I believe summability if absolute summability is equivalent to completeness

Comment: @ If a normed linear space is complete then every absolutely convergent series converges and if every absolutely convergent series converges, then the normed linear space is complete. But do we know any such result which says that in a complete space every convergent series is absolutely convergent?

Comment: I misread, sorry. =)

Comment: By the Dvoretsky-Rogers Theorem (Google it), if every unconditionally convergent series  in the Banach space $X$ is absolutely convergent, then $X$ is finite dimensional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only such Hilbert space is the zero-dimensional one.  Otherwise, let $x$ be any nonzero vector, and consider the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n} x$$

Comment: @ Eldredge: Thanks! Thus in every non-zero Hilbert space, there is a  convergent series which is not absolutely convergent.